# How to keep django from creating join on parent=None

Tags: python, django

I have the follow model (partial) model definition:

```
class Album(models.Model):
  name          = models.CharField(max_length=50, 
                                 null=False, 
                                 blank=True)
  parent        = models.ForeignKey("self",
                                  null = True,
                                  default = None,
                                  blank = True,
                                  help_text="Points to a parent album",
                                  related_name="children")
```

When I run `manage.py debugsqlquery` and examine the generated queries I'm getting a join that should not be there:

```
>>> a_qs = Album.objects.filter(parent=None)
>>> for a in a_qs:
...  print a
...
```

The resulting query is:

```
SELECT "photos_album"."id",
   "photos_album"."name",
   "photos_album"."parent_id",
   "photos_album"."owner_id",
   "photos_album"."order",
   "photos_album"."system",
   "photos_album"."created",
   "photos_album"."last_modified"
FROM "photos_album"
LEFT OUTER JOIN "photos_album" T2 ON ("photos_album"."parent_id" = T2."id")
WHERE T2."id" IS NULL
ORDER BY "photos_album"."order" ASC, "photos_album"."name" ASC  [0.42ms]
```

I am attempting to get rid of the `LEFT OUTER JOIN` I've tried `parent_id=None`, `parent__isnull=True`, and `parent_id__isnull=True` and all generate the join.

How do I do I perform the query without it creating a join?

Comment: Not really an answer.  I use MPTT when it is the correct answer to the problem.  This is not a generic tree problem.  It is a particular issue with django creating a `JOIN` where none is required.  The entire `LEFT OUTER JOIN ... WHERE T2."id" IS NULL` should reduce to a simple `WHERE "photos_album"."parent_id" IS NULL`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way to require in a Django filter that a nullable field be null is to use an `__isnull` argument, not equality:

```
a_qs = Album.objects.filter(parent__isnull=True)
```

But I see that you've tried that. It turns out that this is a known bug in Django, corrected in the current development version but not in 1.5 or sooner:

https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/10790

You could work around the error in the query by using an `extra` clause:

```
a_qs = Album.objects.extra(where=["parent_id is null"])
```

Comment: Thank you Peter DeGlooper, unfortunately that still generates the JOIN, I tried `parent=None`, `parent__isnull=True`, and `parent_id__isnull=True`.  All four generated the `JOIN`

Comment: And I see that your question mentions that you tried that - sorry for overlooking that. It looks like this is a bug in Django: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/10790 - though it looks like 1.6 will be the first version with it fixed.

Comment: +Peter DeGlooper, thank you for finding that bug report.  I'll look into using the workaround documented.

Comment: The `exclude...isnull=False` thing does not avoid the unnecessary join on recent versions of Django - I think the bug log implies that 1.4 changed that. At least, assuming that's what "something happened between 1.3 and 1.4 that made this problem wildly worse" refers to.

Comment: I think the only likely fix is going to be to use `extra` to tightly control the SQL generated - the example I added to my answer works on some of my test models.